# Which code should I choose to call a delegate method?

Tags: c#, delegates

To handle an event, I use the code as below:

```
obj.Evt += new EvtEventHandler(DoEvt);
```

or

```
obj.Evt += DoEvt;
```

will make same result;

So... Please tell me which one I should choose! And why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `Evt` is typed as `EvtEventHandler` then there is no difference (unless you use C# 1.2, where only the first exists).

Use whichever you want.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter. Behind the scenes, both ways are the same (the compiler generates the same code). See "13.6 Method group conversions" in the ECMA C# specification (you can read it [here](http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334%3a_13.6_Method_group_conversions)).

Answer (score 3):

Yes they make the same result. however if you are using `1.0` or `1.1` you must specify `EvtEventHandler`, for later versions `2.0` and above you can get rid from it.

Answer (score 2):

For IL, they are the same,

```
  IL_0020:  newobj     instance void [mscorlib]System.EventHandler::.ctor(object,
                                                                     native int)
  IL_0025:  callvirt   instance void ConsoleApplication15.A::DoEvt(class [mscorlib]System.EventHandler)
```

But I think the first one is meaningful for maintaining your code.